# Determine the number of bound states admitted in Schrodinger system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

Is there a general method for determining the number of bound states admitted by a potential in the Schrodinger equation?

Certainly the number of dimensions must factor in somehow: the delta potential for example is pathological in 3D, whereas it admits a single bound state in 1D.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210272/

Comment: @Gert this is in NO WAY a duplicate of that question, but is tangentially related.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Formula (1) in my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16325/2451) is a semi-classical formula for the number $N(E)$ of bound states below energy-level $E$ in 1D.